Astro Project Renders Blank Page on Cloudflare with No Console Errors
Problem Description
I've completed my Astro project and it works fine locally in both development and build modes. However, when I deploy it to Cloudflare, I'm getting a blank page with no console errors.
What I've Tried
Created a custom index.astro and layout without components, which works.
When I add components, the component doesn't render.
Project Details
Using Astro with SSR (Server-Side Rendering)
Deploying to Cloudflare
here is the astro.config.mjs file

import cloudflare from "@astrojs/cloudflare";

import react from "@astrojs/react";

import icon from "astro-icon";

import tailwind from "@astrojs/tailwind";

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  output: "server",
  adapter: cloudflare({
    platformProxy: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  }),

  integrations: [
    react(),
    icon(),
    tailwind({
      applyBaseStyles: false,
    }),
  ],
});

Questions
Why might my components fail to render on Cloudflare while working locally?
Are there any known issues with Astro SSR on Cloudflare?
What debugging steps can I take to identify the problem, given that there are no console errors?

You could debug locally using wrangler. But Cloudflare workers are just a different runtime than Node.js or browser. I'm not even sure React supports that runtime.

i upload it on netlify and works fine i assume it be a issue or i miss a configuration in Cloudflare adapter

I had the same error, my problem was in .env variables. Cloudflare isn't working well with them. Solution was:
  adapter: cloudflare(),
  vite: {
    define: {
        "process.env": process.env
    }
  }

